# ffmpeg: keyframe extraction with pts

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming

I have an ffmpeg newbie question, I am extracting keyframes from streams using this command:
`ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i {0} -vsync 0 -r 30 -f image2 keyframe-%09d.jpeg`

However, instead of an auto-incrementing counter, I would like to save by frame `pts`. for example keyframe-0003456.jpg as the pts. How can I mod the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -copyts -skip_frame nokey -i {0} -vsync 0 -r 1000 -f image2 -frame_pts 1 keyframe-%09d.jpeg
```

This will print the pts as milliseconds in the filename.